Position Graphics using FigInset in SciDraw
I would like to position Graphics into FigurePanel of SciDraw using real coordinates. It means that I would like to place Graphics star5 at position realpos in FigurePanel (see code below).
I am not sure how to do that. I used scaled coordintes to do that but the Graphics star5 is little bit shifted from the desired position (denoted by black circle). Here is my code:
Quiet[Needs["SciDraw`"]];
xrange = {50, 100};
yrange = {50, 100};

star[n_] := 
  Graphics[{Line[
     Table[{Cos[t*(n - 1)^2/n*Pi], Sin[t*(n - 1)^2/n*Pi]}, {t, 0, 
       n}]]}, ImageSize -> 100];
star5 = star[5];

realpos = {75., 75.};
scaledpos = {(realpos[[1]] - xrange[[1]])/(xrange[[2]] - 
      xrange[[1]]), (realpos[[2]] - yrange[[1]])/(yrange[[2]] - 
      yrange[[1]])};

insetScaled = Inset[star5, Scaled[scaledpos]];

Figure[FigurePanel[{
   FigLine[{{realpos[[1]], yrange[[1]]}, {realpos[[1]], yrange[[2]]}}],
   FigLine[{{xrange[[1]], realpos[[1]]}, {xrange[[2]], realpos[[2]]}}],
   DataPlot[{realpos}, 
    DataSymbol -> {SymbolSize -> 10, SymbolShape -> "Circle", 
      Color -> Black, ShowFill -> True}, DataLine -> {Show -> False}, 
    DataColumns -> {1, 2}],
   FigInset[Graphics[insetScaled]]
   }, XPlotRange -> {50, 100}, YPlotRange -> {50, 100}
  ], Canvas -> {10, 10}
 ]


I would be grateful for any help.
